# Symfony for visual studio appears error that not exist

Tags: php, symfony, visual-studio-code

I know the error comes from the symfony extension for vscode, but I don't know how to solve it.

Hi, I am using Visual Studio to create a Symfony web application. I was working for a few days and everything was normal. But today I don't know why when I enter the project it shows me lines in red, and a message that says:

[image]

I solved this error with this line in setting.json:

```
"symfony-vscode.phpExecutablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe"
```

But the red lines stay there and the execution of the program works perfect, the only thing is the red lines, look:

[image]

[image]

I know the error comes from the symfony extension for vscode, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: You could probably hover on the red lines or open the `problems view` to see what are the actual issues.

Comment: You need to take your pictures out of the link and actually add them to your question.

Comment: I use Visual Studio on a daily basis but for C#.  Never tried with PHP.  This is just a guess but I suspect it thinks you have an older version of PHP installed.  Poke around the various config menus and see if you can convince it that you have PHP 7.4+ installed.  Assuming that you do of course.  By the way, Visual Studio and VsCode are two completely different things.